# Android apps finger print

Tags: android, google-play

After losing all my codes I've developed a new code. I've the previous fingerprint but in my new apps the fingerprint is different from my existing app on play store.  So how can I replace my new fingerprint with my old fingerprint?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the private key you have used to sign your previous application. If you have it, should not be a problem (you know how as you have signed it once anyway when deploying first time).

If you have lost your private key, there is nothing you can do. You can only upload this app as a new app. Any update of the existing application [must be signed with the same key](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Comment: I've my previous key, So how to replace the new key with my old key?